# How to print an HTML document using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

Recently I started to crawl the web using Puppeteer. Below is a code for extracting a specific product name from the shopping mall.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

    const width = 1600, height = 1040;

    const option = { headless: false, slowMo: true, args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`] };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(option);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const vp = {width: width, height: height};
    await page.setViewport(vp);

    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

    await page.goto('https://shopping.naver.com/home/p/index.nhn');
    await navigationPromise;
    await page.waitFor(2000);

    const textBoxId = 'co_srh_input';
    await page.type('.' + textBoxId, '양말', {delay: 100});
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    await page.waitFor(5000);
    await page.waitForSelector('div.info > a.tit');

    const stores = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.info > a.tit'));
        return links.map(link => link.innerText).slice(0, 10)   // 10개 제품만 가져오기
    });

    console.log(stores);
    await browser.close();

})();
```

I have a question. How can I output the crawled results to an HTML document (without using the database)? Please use sample code to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### fs.writeFile()

You can use the following `write_file` function that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that [resolves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) or [rejects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) when [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) succeeds or fails.

Then, you can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from within your anonymous, asynchronous function and check whether or not the data was written to the file:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const write_file = (file, data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.writeFile(file, data, 'utf8', error => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      reject(false);
    } else {
      resolve(true);
    }
  });
});

(async () => {
  
  // ...
  
  const stores = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.info > a.tit'), link => link.innerText).slice(0, 10); // 10개 제품만 가져오기
  });
  
  if (await write_file('example.html', stores.toString()) === false) {
    console.error('Error: Unable to write stores to example.html.');
  }
  
  // ...
  
});
```

Comment: thanks!! I solved the problem. If I want to insert into <li> inside an HTML document, Can I use Express?

Comment: Hi. would it be possible for you to please have a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287662/using-puppeteer-to-click-and-visit-sub-links

Answer (score 5):

I used what was seen on [blog.kowalczyk.info](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/ea07db1b9bff415ab180b0525f3898f6/advanced-web-spidering-with-puppeteer.html)

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    // hacky defensive move but I don't know a better way:
    // wait a bit so that the browser finishes executing JavaScript
    await page.waitFor(1 * 1000);
    const html = await page.content();
    fs.writeFileSync("index.html", html);
    await browser.close();
}

run();
```