# Using Puppeteer to click main links and clicking sub-links?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer

Simplification :

I have a website with links.
After clicking on each link , it goes to a new page that I need to  visit the links ( by **clicking** , not navigating).

Visualization :

[image]

I've managed to do 99% percent of the job:

```
(async () =>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let url = "https://www.mutualart.com/Artists";
    console.log(`Fetching page data for : ${url}...`);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector(".item.col-xs-3");
    let arrMainLinks: ElementHandle[] = await page.$$('.item.col-xs-3 > a');   //get the main links

    console.log(arrMainLinks.length); // 16


    for (let mainLink of arrMainLinks) //foreach main link let's click it
    {
        let hrefValue =await (await mainLink.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
        console.log("Clicking on " + hrefValue);
        await Promise.all([
                              page.waitForNavigation(),
                              mainLink.click({delay: 100})
                          ]);

        // let's get the sub links
        let arrSubLinks: ElementHandle[] = await page.$$('.slide >a');

        //let's click on each sub click
        for (let sublink of arrSubLinks)
        {
            console.log('██AAA');

            await Promise.all([
                                  page.waitForNavigation(),
                                  sublink.click({delay: 100})
                              ]);
            console.log('██BBB');

            // await page.goBack() 
            break; // for now ...
        }
        break;

    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

**So where is the problem ?**

It reaches the ██AAA
But it never reaches ██BBB

And I get an error :

```
 C:\temp\puppeterr1\app>node server2.js
Fetching page data for : https://www.mutualart.com/Artists...
16
Clicking on https://www.mutualart.com/Artist/Mr--Brainwash/9B3FED6BB81E6B8E
██AAA
(node:17200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\temp\puppeterr1\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:1230:21)
    at <anonymous>
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\temp\puppeterr1\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:144:27)
    at Page.waitForNavigation (C:\temp\puppeterr1\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:599:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\temp\puppeterr1\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:145:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\temp\puppeterr1\app\server2.js:127:30)
    at step (C:\temp\puppeterr1\app\server2.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:\temp\puppeterr1\app\server2.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\temp\puppeterr1\app\server2.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:17200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17200) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Question:**

What am I missing here ?
Why can't it reach the ██BBB ?

[Complete code](https://gist.github.com/RoyiNamir/f87637161ee02b8f6c790bc9b6a4097c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3535

**Original Answer:**

Update , I've managed to solve it but not via  the regular way that I wanted.

It seems that there is a problem with `ElementHandle`. Which is why I've moved to pure **DOM** objects.

**I'm still** interested with a more intuitive solution rather by dealing with ElementHandle :

Anyway here is my solution :

```
(async () =>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let url = "https://www.mutualart.com/Artists";
    console.log(`Fetching page data for : ${url}...`);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector(".item.col-xs-3");

    let arrMainLinks = await page.evaluate(() =>
                                           {

                                               return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item.col-xs-3 > a'));
                                           });
    console.log(arrMainLinks.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < arrMainLinks.length; i++) //get the main links
    {


        await page.evaluate((a) =>
                            {


                                return ([...document.querySelectorAll('.item.col-xs-3 > a')][a] as HTMLElement ).click();
                            }, i);
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        let arrSubLinks2 = await page.evaluate(() =>
                                               {
                                                   return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide>a'));
                                               });
        console.log(arrSubLinks2.length);
        for (let j = 0; j < arrSubLinks2.length; j++)
        {
            console.log('███AAA');
            await page.evaluate((a) =>
                                {

                                    return ([...document.querySelectorAll('.slide>a')][a] as HTMLElement) .click();
                                }, j);

            await page.waitForNavigation();
            let ddd: ElementHandle[] = await page.$$('.artist-name');
            console.log(ddd.length);

            console.log('███BBB');
            await page.waitFor(2000);
            await page.goBack();
            console.log('███CCC');

        }
        await page.waitFor(2000);
        await page.goBack();
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Apologies for my deleted answer - what I suggested worked once but only once and so I wanted to go back and retry it to make it more robust. I just didn't have time to come back to it yet.